# Magento - Trouble loading module layout xml file

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm creating a simple sample module in magento 1.9 and I am hoping to do display a custom block on the front end product page - through my module; however I have stumbled in trouble early on.

In my modules config.xml I have defined a front end layout update, below as the full config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MP_SampleModule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MP_SampleModule>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <MP_SampleModule>
                    <file>samplemodule.xml</file>
                </MP_SampleModule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

I have confirmed the module is loading.

For the layout file, I created samplemodule.xml : 
\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\samplemodule.xml

rwd is my active theme.

the samplemodule.xml contents are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle">
                <rel>DID THIS WORK??</rel>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

However it seems Magento is not picking up this file at all.  I have tried placing invalid xml in the samplemodule.xml in the hope Magento would throw an error confirming it is at least being loaded, but as no error is thrown I'm lead to believe it is simply being ignored.

I've read countless other similar questions on SO and on other sites but i've hit a brick wall so any insight into the issue would be welcomed and anything leading to a solution would be applauded.

Thanks

Comment: Can you place the complete XML files? Is the module loading?

Comment: Hi Ronn), the module is indeed loading.  Original questions has been edited to provide the complete XML Files.

Comment: Have you checked the magneto log files? Also edit the index.php file and turn on 'Developer Mode' see if it throws any errors for you, having a look through the xml you provided it looks ok. I presume you have the correct file in the etc/modules folder and it's in the right codePool etc?

Comment: I would also try moving the samplemodule.xml to app/design/frontend/base/default/layout to see if this works - it's not absolutely necessary  to have the layout file in your theme because magneto will use its  fall back system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of not making any progress with this, I decided to try again.  In the end I changed the contents of my files to the following which seems to have done the trick:

\app\code\community\MP\SampleModule\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MP_SampleModule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MP_SampleModule>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <MP_SampleModule module="MP_SampleModule">
                    <file>mp_samplemodule.xml</file>
                </MP_SampleModule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\mp_samplemodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template"
               name="test"
               template="mp/samplemodule/test.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This now correctly outputs contents of test.phtml (\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\mp\samplemodule\test.phtml) near the end of the page.

Thanks for all the insights provided which was helpful in finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are putting it in your theme folder. Second the updates reference the Module Name not its namespace so it would be

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <Sample_Module>
                <file>samplemodule.xml</file>
            </Sample_Module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then try adding this: `<layout version="0.1.0">` instead of layout. Then add this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle"><rel>DID THIS WORK??</re></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

this will set the title of every page.

Other things to check: is the module being loaded?

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for the suggestions.  Unfortunately still not having any luck.  I've confirmed the module is loaded.  Layout XML file still seems to be completely ignored.  I have edited my original question providing full dumps of the files concerned in the hope something can be spotted.